# Operation of Python's LRU cache

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got the following code:

```
def sharpe(self):
    return (self.weighted_returns()/self.weighted_returns().std())*np.sqrt(252)
```

Where `self.weighted_returns()` has a `@lru_cache(maxsize=None)` decorator.

Will `self.weighted_returns()` be calculated once or twice?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Do you know what `lru_cache` does? If so what are you confused about?

Comment: why are you even using lru_cache for this and why not cache the calculation into the instance itself?

Comment: I cannot see why it should be called twice. It is on the same line but the calls are evaluated in a strict order.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Pretty sure lru_cache hashes the params and just returns the same result when it's called again with the same parameters. I expect in this case it will be called just once.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I was trying to make the code shorter and cleaner. Should I cache it on the instance? What's the advantage of doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `functools.lru_cache` for this. But if you're only caching the calculations for `self` and the function does not use an argument, it is an overkill.

Rather, I'd steal the lazy [`reify`](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/decorator.html#pyramid.decorator.reify) decorator from Pyramid:

```
class reify(object):
    def __init__(self, wrapped):
        self.wrapped = wrapped
        update_wrapper(self, wrapped)

    def __get__(self, inst, objtype=None):
        if inst is None:
            return self
        val = self.wrapped(inst)
        setattr(inst, self.wrapped.__name__, val)
        return val
```

And use it on `weighted_returns`, turning it into a lazily calculated attribute:

```
@reify
def weighted_returns(self):
    # calculate the returns using self normally
    return returns
```

Then your calculation would be

```
self.weighted_returns / self.weighted_returns.std() * np.sqrt(252)
```

(notice the lack of parentheses).

Unlike `functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)` which will keep a dictionary of unlimited size (it is going to increase in size until you kill the program), the `reify` decorator caches the calculation result on the instance itself. If the instance is garbage-collected, then so are its cached weighted returns.